# phpmyadmin no nginx

Tags: phpmyadmin, nginx

Bem, instalei o ubuntu server 16.04 no meu computador local, porém quando vou acessar o phpmyadmin ele da erro 404.
Estou acessando pelo endereço ip_local/phpmyadmin

Aqui está o meu virtual server

phpmyadmin:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; #I use php7.0 : it's a problem ?
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Estou utilizando a versão 7.0 do php e a versão do nginx é 1.10.3

Comment: Já tentou adicionar um `server_name` ?

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso e não deu certo.

Comment: Se possível atualiza seu exemplo. Da forma que está, basta acessar o endereço do `server_name`. Não é necessário adicionar o *path `/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr é porque tem o site principal e o phpmyadmin, ai queria que quando o usuário acessar o /phpmyadmin ser redirecionado pra /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Sem precisar criar o link simbolico na /var/www/html/

Comment: Entendi. Neste caso você poderá adicionar o `root /path/to` dentro do *location*, por exemplo: `location /phpmyadmin { root /usr/share; }`. Porém, você terá um problema de segurança.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Fiz isso mas ainda continua retornando 404.

virtual server do pma https://hastebin.com/facoxehuvi.nginx

E qual seria esse problema de segurança ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76199/discussion-between-valdeir-psr-and-luiz).